# jfreechart.jar file not supporting

Tags: windows-server-2008, java

I have some code where I am making bar graph with the help of jfreechart.jar file
its working ok in my local system but its not working in my server showing this error-

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
C:\report\CreateBarChart.java:13: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
C:\report\CreateBarChart.java:14: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGEncodeParam;
C:\report\CreateBarChart.java:15: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
C:\report\CreateBarChart.java:179: error: cannot find symbol
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder2 = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fos);
  symbol:   class JPEGImageEncoder
  location: class CreateBarChart
C:\report\CreateBarChart.java:179: error: cannot find symbol
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder2 = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(fos);
  symbol:   variable JPEGCodec
  location: class CreateBarChart
C:\report\CreateBarChart.java:180: error: cannot find symbol
        JPEGEncodeParam param2 = encoder2.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(img);
```

I have added all required jar and import code but still its showing this error when I am going to buid jar.
but its not showing error in netbeans only showing when I am going to build jar and working ok in local system so I am thinking this is server problem. 
I have added these jar -

```
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13-experimental.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13-swt.jar
```

so is it server problem or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I think you're running a different JDK version than JFreeChart supports. `com.sun` is the internal Sun-jdk only classes. Those classes will work in Sun's JDK, but they will not in others like OpenJDK or IcedTea. They also are subject to change between versions

Solution: First, install Sun's JRE or make sure your already running Sun's. If that doesn't work, downgrade (or upgrade) to Java 6, as that's what it seems JFreeChart wants

Answer (score 0):

> I think only an issue is adding those Jar files to CLASS_PATH on environment variables of system.